# Wrap content to a text with clipped shape in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a text compose and I want to apply a triangle shape on it, I applied the tringle successfully but the text doesn't wrap inside the triangle shape, it seems that the shape doesn't cut the view to be tringle, it only draws above it or thing like that.

here is the code:

```
Text(
 modifier = Modifier
       .clip(TriangleShape)
        .background(
            Brush.horizontalGradient(
               listOf(
                  Color(0xff4F0D37),
                  Color(0xffD73046)
                 )
               )
            ),
  text = "150",
  color = Color.White,
)
```

[image]

Any tip will be appreciated :)

Comment: How do you want to clip the text in a triangle? Reducing the font size or increasing the size of the shape?

Comment: Increasing the size of the shape in a consistent way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it:

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(TriangleShape)
        .background(
            Brush.horizontalGradient(
                listOf(
                    Color(0xff4F0D37),
                    Color(0xffD73046)
                )
            )
        )
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

            layout(placeable.width * 2, placeable.height * 2) {
                placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        },
    text = "150",
    color = Color.White,
)
```

I used the `layout` lambda expression to double the width and the height of the composable, while keeping the everything else the same. Took some messing around with rows and columns but I think this is a fitting solution.

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the width of the shape will increase badly when the number becomes larger, is there a way to keep the shape looking consistent with any number?

Comment: I understand, so let's assume the number is 1000000000, what would you like the shape to look like? for it to be displayed properly, and by that I mean contained within the triangle and still visible, this is the way to go (I mean geometry-wise)

Comment: I would like to increase the height(somehow) when the width increases, so the tringle doesn't lose its shape.
let's assume that value is "100" then -> width = 36 and height = 30 so the shape looks good, but when the value be "100000" so -> the width = 100 and height = 30 in this case the tringle lose its shape.
in other words, I need a way to increase the height when the width increases to keep the shape looks good.

Comment: You can change the height however you want in the line "layout(placeable.width * 2, placeable.height * 2)", just replace the height with whatever value you need. Your description isn't concise enough for me to provide you a proper solution. You can pre-define the angles you want the triangle to have and then, with the top line as a base, calculate the height in order to get the precise angle you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
BoxWithConstraints{
val constraints = size
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(TriangleShape)
        .background(
            Brush.horizontalGradient(
                listOf(
                    Color(0xff4F0D37),
                    Color(0xffD73046)
                )
            )
        ),
    text = "150",
    color = Color.White,
    fontSize = (constraints.width / 2) // ... Modify if necessary
)
}
```

Here I am using the `size` parameter exposed by BoxWithConstraints. This is the size of the box, which I am storing in a variable to later re-use to set the font size of the text accordingly. Text positioning can be done easily. Use Modifier.align(TopStart)

Comment: Can you put some explanation?

Comment: I want to size the shape based on the content size, I don't want to change the font size of the text, sorry but your answer not clear to me.

Comment: In that case, what is the problem with MichaelThePotatoe's answer? The height and width will be scaled equally so it should not distort the shape, that's what I think.

Comment: The problem is when the number becomes larger like "100000", so the width of text will be much bigger than the height therefore the triangle will be inconsistent.